# UDPClient messages not receiving

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets, udp, udpclient

I am semi-new to C#, VS, and .NET. I have some basics down, however I am having a really hard time communicating with UDP with a servo controller that I have.

I am hoping someone can guide me on what is wrong with my code, how this works, and what is the best approach for receiving messages.

My first step is to broadcast a "who" message and when my servo sees this, I will get a response back with information about about that servo.

```
public void Discover()
        {
            byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("who");
            IPEndPoint targetEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, LINKPORT);
            IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            System.Console.WriteLine("New Transimission Sequence:");
            foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                if (ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
                {
                    foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in ni.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                    {
                        if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        {
                            IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip.Address.ToString()), LINKPORT);

                            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(localEndpoint);
                            udpClient.Send(message, message.Length, targetEndPoint);

                            UdpClient udpClientB = new UdpClient(remoteEndPoint);
                            udpClientB.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
                            string recvMessage;
                            try
                            {
                                recvMessage = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(udpClientB.Receive(ref remoteEndPoint));
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                recvMessage = e.Message;
                            }

                            System.Console.WriteLine(recvMessage);

                            udpClient.Close();
                            udpClientB.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            System.Console.WriteLine("==========================================================================================");

            return;
        }
```

This is what I currently have. I understand it is very crude at the moment, however I can't even get this to work... I am attempting to broadcast a 'who' message across all of my network cards in the code above. And then using `udpClientB`, I want to receive the message. I have tried using the `udpClient` and that didn't work, and that's why I created `udpClientB`. I have also tried creating a separate thread that just listens on that port and nothing...

Right now this is what I am getting on my console window.

```
New Transimission Sequence:
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
==========================================================================================
```

When I tried using `udpClient` as the sender and receiver, I was getting "who" in my console window... What am I doing wrong? What is going on?

I tripled check and the messages are being sent and I am responding to the message when it reaches my servo controller, that is happening.

Also a question for after this is done, what is the best approach for this kind of stuff? This code is getting hit by a windows form button, eventually I want to display everyone who responded on a windows form list. Should I create asynchronous function calls? Use a 'Timer' to constantly listen and empty the ethernet buffer? Create a new thread to listen? Or what I am currently doing, just in-line?

Thank you for your time in reading this.

Comment: Remove your receivetimeout, or just raise him a little bit and try again.

Comment: udp has no requirement to make it to the other side..

Comment: I raised the timeout to 5 seconds and I am getting the same thing. Looking at the transmission in WireShark, I am responding at an average turnaround time of 0.00035 seconds... This isn't on a network, I am connected to it directly (through a small router).

Comment: Does anyone else have this problem or some insight? I still can't figure out what's happening.

Comment: you must first "receive" inside a diferent thread and then send the message